# python - using copy.deepcopy on dotdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, deep-copy

I have used dotdict in various locations around my app to enhance readability of my code. Little did I know that this would cause many problems down the road. One particularly annoying case is the fact that it does not seem to be compatible with the copy library.

**This is what I mean by dotdict**

```
class DotDict(dict):
    """dot.notation access to dictionary attributes"""
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

i.e. a way of accessing dictionary attributes as such: `dictionary.attribute`

When I try

```
nested_dico = DotDict({'example':{'nested':'dico'}})
copy.deepcopy(nested_dico)
```

I get the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    167                     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    168                     if reductor:
--> 169                         rv = reductor(4)
    170                     else:
    171                         reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I assume this is because it does not recognise my class DotDict and thus considers it to be NoneType.

Does anyone know a way around this? Maybe override the copy library's valid types?

Comment: What's a dotdict and where does it come from? Can you rewrite it to throw an AttributeError when `__reduce__` is accessed?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and point to the specific library you're using. Is it https://github.com/vkuznet/DotDict?

Comment: Would be good to see the code that causes the error if possible?

Comment: implement your own copy... traverse the dict and return a new one

Comment: Question updated as per comments. Could you please show an example of this @shahaf

Comment: "enhance readability of my code"... the fact that attributes and items have been munged together I would argue decreases readability of code. Yes, you don't access the items using strings, but you now have less visibility of what's going on in terms of the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html). I would really consider refactoring to not use DotDict.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking into the spot where the error occurs, `reductor` is not `None`, but it's a built-in function, meaning the error occurs somewhere in C code where we can't see a traceback. But my guess is that it tries to get a method that it's not sure exists, ready to catch an `AttributeError` if not. Instead this calls `.get` which returns `None` without an error, so it tries to call the method.

This behaves correctly:

```
class DotDict(dict):
    """dot.notation access to dictionary attributes"""

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return self[item]
        except KeyError as e:
            raise AttributeError from e

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

a = DotDict(x=1, b=2)

print(deepcopy(a))
```

I know that's not the same behaviour as your original class, and you won't be able to use `.` for optional keys, but I think it's necessary to avoid errors like this with external code that expects your class to behave in a predictable way.

EDIT: here is a way to implement deepcopy and preserve the original `__getattr__`:

```
class DotDict(dict):
    """dot.notation access to dictionary attributes"""

    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo=None):
        return DotDict(deepcopy(dict(self), memo=memo))
```

Tests:

```
dd = DotDict(x=1, b=2, nested=DotDict(y=3))

copied = deepcopy(dd)
print(copied)
assert copied == dd
assert copied.nested == dd.nested
assert copied.nested is not dd.nested
assert type(dd) is type(copied) is type(dd.nested) is type(copied.nested) is DotDict
```

Answer (score 0):

implementing a copy for custom data structure is fairly easy, smth like so

```
def my_dict_copy(d):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items()}

d1 = { 'a' :1,'b':2}
d2 = my_dict_copy(d1)
d3 = d1
d1['a'] = 2

print(d1)
print(d2)
print(d3)
```

output

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

you didn't provided your implementation of dict, I assume it respond to class methods like `items()` if not, there must be a way you can iterate all the keys and values

also I assume the key and values are immutable objects and not data structure otherwise you need to make a copy of 'k' and 'v' also (maybe using the origin `copy` lib)

Comment: I need to copy a nested dictionary, that has many different layers in it with various types of data types (lists, dataframes, strings, dictionaries...)

Comment: @Ludo post your code for all the data types need to be copy, so we can make specific solution